# Env variable for rundeck.feature.jobLifecyclePlugin.enabled?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, environment-variables, rundeck

I was trying to run rundeck on docker image on kubernetes. I wanted to know if there is an env variable for `rundeck.feature.jobLifecyclePlugin.enabled` to be added on the docker compose file. I couldn't find it anywhere in the documents. Would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `RUNDECK_FEATURE_JOBLIFECYCLEPLUGIN_ENABLED: 'true'` on "environment" section on compose file like [this](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/config/docker-compose.yml), but that create this line on `rundeck-config.properties` file: `rundeck.feature.joblifecycleplugin.enabled=true` (all lowercase, and we need `rundeck.feature.jobLifecyclePlugin.enabled=true`, the configuration is case sensitive).

You can add it using [Remco](https://github.com/HeavyHorst/remco). Take a look at [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck) (check the "Extending Configuration" section), [here](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/tree/master/config) a good example to test.

In my case, I added this in the `rundeck-config-extra.properties` file (at `mydocker/remco/templates/` path).

```
# adding extra stuff to rundeck-config.properties file
rundeck.feature.jobLifecyclePlugin.enabled={{ getv("/rundeck/feature/joblifecycleplugin/enabled", "true") }}
```

And this on `rundeck-config.properties-extra.toml` (at `mydocker/remco/resources.d/`      path)

```
[[template]]
    src         = "${REMCO_TEMPLATE_DIR}/rundeck-config-extra.properties"
    dst         = "${REMCO_TMP_DIR}/rundeck-config/rundeck-config-extra.properties"
    mode        = "0644"
```

My `docker-compose.yaml` (at `mydocker/` path):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  rundeckserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        url: http://localhost:4440
    ports:
      - "4440:4440"
    restart: always
```

My `Dockerfile` (at `mydocker/` path, also copy an example plugin obtained [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/tree/master/examples/example-java-job-lifecycle-plugin)):

```
FROM rundeck/rundeck:3.2.4

COPY --chown=rundeck:root remco /etc/remco
COPY --chown=rundeck:root volume/job-lifecycle-3.2.3-20200221.jar /home/rundeck/libext/
ARG url=""
ENV RUNDECK_SERVER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
ENV RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=$url
```

Then you need to do (at `mydocker/` path):

`docker-compose build`

And later:

`docker-compose up`

That adds this line in the `rundeck-config.properties` file:

```
# adding extra stuff to rundeck-config.properties file
rundeck.feature.jobLifecyclePlugin.enabled=true
```

Finally, take a look at the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GlSm.jpg).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am trying to edit the docker entry script to edit the existing properties is their a way to edit the rundeck-config.properfities file here? Also, I have a rundeck-config.properties files used before, anyway I can just use that file completely?

Comment: Yes, you can copy your file from your  system to your container with docker cp, take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Comment: Or copy the file in the dockerfile (check the COPY sentence in my Dockerfile example). More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy